# How can I order /dev/sdX block devices names by hardware path on Linux?

Tags: linux, udev, block-device

I know about [persistent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/persistent_block_device_naming), using `/dev/disk/by-{id,path,uuid,...}` and how it is best practice to use those persistent names in system config (`fstab`, scripts) instead of `/dev/sda` for example.

However, for my own system administrator convenience, I would like my Linux system to order those block devices by their hardware path (the `by-path`) for assigning `/dev/sdX` names to them.

As of now, I have:

```
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/*ata-?
lrwxrwxrwx [...] /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-1 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx [...] /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-2 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx [...] /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-3 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx [...] /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-4 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx [...] /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5 -> ../../sdd
```

And I would rather have `ata-{1,2,3,4,5}` respectively named `sd{a,b,c,d,e}`.

**How can I force those `/dev/sdX` names to follow that order?**

Comment: Although there may ways to force things in initramfs before any drive is in use, it would only hold until there is a failure or disconnect of any of those drives... so it still can't guarantee anything. Is it worth it? You can easily generate convenience aliases with a custom udev rule if you don't like the `by-*/*` default ones.

Comment: Generally UEFI/BIOS discovers drives in port order. And then kernel assigns those drives in order discovered. So make sure the drive you want as sda is in port 0, sdb in port 1 etc. NVMe drives often are before SATA drives in drive order.

Comment: @oldfred Before I upgraded my kernel and started to use UEFI boot, that was the behaviour: all disks were named in port order. Now, I'm using UEFI and a newer kernel, and things started to change. I will check my startup ("BIOS") config.

Comment: It may vary by UEFI vendor's implementation. My UEFI systems are all in port order. But drive speed may also make a difference. Maybe why my NVMe drive is found first.  If SSD it may be discovered faster that a HDD. And some HDDs are faster than others.